# Lock screen not locking with LDAP on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, pam, ldap, gdm

On my system some users authenticate with LDAP, others have their password stored locally (standard).

The problem is that LDAP-users cannot lock the screen. When pressing `Windows-Key + L` the screen saver is activated, but when a key is pressed (e.g., `Enter`) one is not prompted for the password.
For the other users, the lock screen works as expected.

Sidenote: the user login (terminal and GDM) works as expected, it's just the lock screen.

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     sufficient    pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
#session     required      pam_unix.so
session     required      pam_ldap.so
```

/etc/pam.d/password-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     sufficient    pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

In addition, I configured the following files: /etc/nsswitch.conf, /etc/openldap/ldap.conf and /etc/nslcd.conf.

System: CentOS 7, Gnome 3

The content of which other file matters in this context?
Any help is highly appreciated!

**Follow up**: We did not get this issue fixed and decided to switch to `sssd` and an authentication via active directory (which our institution provided, too). Now everything works as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem. If possible, kindly post your solution as an Answer so that others like me will be able to profit. Please include the configuration of sssd and/or PAM and/or any other, perhaps removing your server name and other sensitive data.